# Keywords in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that responds to certain keywords but for some reason I can't seem to get it to work. E.g. if I were  to say "This game is so hard" it would respond with "Hehe: Hard". (Childish I know). How would I edit this code to make it work because at the moment it refuses to work. thank you

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "hard" in message.content.lower():
        await message.channel.send('Hehe "Hard"')
        return
```

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? This part of the code is not wrong, apart from that it will cause recursion issues. Can you show a bit more of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Where is this supposed to happen? In a server? Do other functions work, is your bot functioning at all? This code seems to have worked for me:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if not message.author.bot and "hard" in message.content.lower():
            await message.channel.send('Hehe "Hard"')
```

Would it be possible for you to send all of the code you currently have?

Comment: It was a simple logic error. Thank you. The issue was the bot was responding to it's own messages. Thank you very much! [This problem](https://imgur.com/a/szLfu90)  is no more

Comment: @BenLea: Since it sounds as though the `not message.author.bot` condition solved the problem, please remember to accept this as the answer.